# is there a better way to emulate import exceptions in python 3

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm currently trying to refactor a bunch of tools/modules from python 2 to python 3, but ATM keeping compatibility between both worlds to be able to operate a smooth transition.

In most of my modules I had the infamous

```
import exceptions
```

to be able to use `exceptions.SystemExit` for instance.

I have found a way to do that:

1. **replace the exceptions import by this code:**

   try:
       # python 2
       from exceptions import *
   except:
       pass
2. **remove all `exceptions.` prefixes (no problem with that)**

Is there a way to improve the first part? (let alone the python version test which amounts to the same thing)

Comment: Why did you write it as `exceptions.ExceptionName` in the first place? All exceptions are available in the built-in namespace by default in both Py2/Py3.

Comment: you're right! This must be a remnant of python 2.5 or me reading something a long time ago and copying/pasting some same obsolete code. Thanks (that was some lame question!)

Comment: Hm, probably the second, as far as `2.4` the [docs on Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/release/2.4.4/lib/module-exceptions.html) stated that they are automatically available. Removing all references to `exceptions` is your best option here unless I'm missing something.